# Handle thousands emails sending by groups of 500 with Symfony 2

Tags: email, symfony, cron, swiftmailer

I am working on a mailing tool with Symfony 2.1 framework and SwiftMailer.

This tool needs to handle thousands of emails, but by groups of 500 because of a smtp server constraint (I can't modify it). It needs to wait few minutes between each wave.

I totally don't know how to do this.

The server running the app is on a Windows machine with Apache, and PHP 5.4. I could use a CRON task but I didn't find anything about CRON and Symfony (I found that with Symfony 1.1, not really up to date).

Comment: Are you using swiftmailer/other library or plain php(mail) ? Anyway, this might help: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/spool.html

Comment: Thanks ! I'm using SwiftMailer so it may be the answer for my question. As it seems to handle the "sending by groups" problem, I need now to create a CRON with Symfony2 and the swiftmailer pool.

Comment: @VadimAshikhman, please make an answer from your comment so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Symfony's built-in Command component here. You're probably familiar with the normal Commands that come packaged with Symfony... Things like `app/console generate:bundle`, etc.

You can use the ContainerAwareCommand class to write your own.

Here are the steps you'll need to take:

- Keep a queue of emails that need to be sent (probably in a database table)
- Create a class extending ContainerAwareCommand, and make the command name something like "email:send:partial"

  - This class should check for the existence of unsent emails from the database. If there is any, it should send up to 500 of them, and then either remove or update the records in the database to reflect the fact that they were sent.
  - By the way, ContainerAwareCommand is, of course, container-aware... Which means it has access to services like Monolog, Twig, and, most importantly here, Doctrine. So you'll be able to retrieve unsent emails from the database table using `$this->getContainer()->get("doctrine")`.
- In cron, set up a regular job using the interval provided by your mail server (plus a minute or two to account for execution delays). The command for this will be `/path/to/symfony/app/console email:send:partial`

That should get you there. Here are a few references for the ContainerAwareCommand class:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/console_command.html

http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.html

Comment: I will use this method.
Instead of cron, I could also execute the php command directly (with the PHP method `exec()` ), with a `sleep()` in the command. I think it should also work ?

Comment: It makes sense to me that you'd use `sleep()`. I almost suggested it, but I don't like the idea that the current execution might collide with a previous execution. Your call. However, I don't understand why you'd use `exec()`. The point of the ContainerAwareCommand class is that it executes PHP code without resulting in a View. Where are you going to be calling `exec()`?

Comment: You're right. I forgot that it will needs to be called in the code somewhere. 
So let's CRON that !

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution for this issue in the [How to Spool Email](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html) part of the Symfony Cookbook.